# What kind of attack?

Tags: wireshark, packet

[image]
I was able to find the Teardrop Attack.
However, there is another one but I couldn't explain it. It keeps getting the warning: Source MAC must not be a group address. Is this some sort of ARP spoofing to steal data?

Edit 1: Could there be a chance that a botnet auto-generate MAC address for packets but didn't work as expected?

[capture file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IPk715R7RR9cNDEknJcHH64eU0YqnWZH/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Bit 0 of the first octet, 0D in this case, indicates **single device** or **group**. It's analagous to multicast at the IP level. If the first octet is **odd**, as in **0D**, it indicates group.

If your application needs to send to multiple devices, it sends **to** a goup address.

It does not make any sense to originate **from** a group address.

This would be a poorly configured packet generator on your local network.

As to what it's trying to accomplish, I'm not sure. From the IP addresses, I'm guessing this is probably a VM based lab you're using.

Comment: This was indeed in VM lab. I'm think to go different way by ignore this warning and find another security problem. But couldn't find one so far.